# Where to find Apollo lunar landing checklists?

Tags: apollo-program, crewed-spaceflight, apollo-11

Is [this](https://www.ibiblio.org/apollo/Documents/Apollo11-LM-TimelineBook-excerpts.pdf) the only document where I can read the checklists for Apollo lunar landing? They look more sidenotes than real checklists, and they contain hundreds of acronyms; I would expect instead a "checklist book" with "acronyms appendix", but can't find it.

[image: timeline with checklists]

I see some cover pages of checklist books, but not for Lunar Module landing, and anyway all on auction on Sotheby's...

[image: cover1]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is the checklist. It's called the LM Timeline Book. This is the corresponding page from Apollo 13.

[image]

Acronym lists are not typically included in NASA human spaceflight checklists. The users are expected to know the acronyms.

Full list:

- [Apollo 11](https://www.ibiblio.org/apollo/Documents/Apollo11-LM-TimelineBook-excerpts.pdf)
- [Apollo 12](https://history.nasa.gov/afj/ap12fj/pdf/a12_lmtb.pdf) - Source: https://space.stackexchange.com/a/41288/6944
- [Apollo 13](https://history.nasa.gov/afj/ap13fj/pdf-hr/a13-lm-timeline-19700316.pdf) - Source: https://history.nasa.gov/afj/ap13fj/a13-documents.html
- [Apollo 14](https://www.hq.nasa.gov/alsj/a14/a14_lmtlb_reformat.pdf) - Source: https://space.stackexchange.com/a/39946/6944
- [Apollo 15](https://readux.ecds.emory.edu/books/readux:spgjt/) - Source: https://readux.ecds.emory.edu/books/readux:spgjt/
- [Apollo 16](https://www.hq.nasa.gov/alsj/a16/a16LM_Timeline.html) - Source: https://space.stackexchange.com/a/40904/6944
- [Apollo 17](https://www.history.nasa.gov/alsj/a17/A17LM_TimelineBook.pdf) - Source: https://www.history.nasa.gov/alsj/a17/A17LM_TimelineBook.html

Comment: I found a "crazy" repository with hundreds of Apollo checklists in XLS format! https://github.com/orbiternassp/NASSP/tree/Orbiter2016/Doc/Project%20Apollo%20-%20NASSP/Checklists

Comment: I edit your answer as to have the full list of links

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to the very useful answer from @Organic Marble, I was able to locate all the checklists (links are in his answer); here is a comparison between the 6 touchdown/stay/nostay checklists:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Note: I think there is a typo in Apollo 14 checklist: the number in brackets usually indicates the number of identical controls to operate; sometimes they wrote "(2)", other times "(both)", but for Apollo 14 we see "(9" without closing bracket, possibly an error in copying the "(2)" from a poorly readable copy of timeline book:

[image: typo]