# On the LM, what is the difference between ABORT and ABORT STAGE?

Tags: apollo-program, abort, lunar-module

The LM had both ABORT and ABORT STAGE buttons. What was the difference and in which scenario would each be used?

Answer (score 10):

> The **abort switch** is actuated to initiate an abort, using only the descent engine. *Actuation of this switch causes the following events to occur: a command signal is sent to arm the descent engine; a signal is sent (via instrumentation) to telemetry to indicate that the LEM is preparing for an abort; and a signal is sent to the LGC and AGS to compute and execute the abort trajectory,using the abort program.*
>
> The **abort stage switch** is actuated to initiate an abort, using
> only the ascent engine. *Actuation of this switch causes the following events to occur: a command signal is sent to electroexplosive devices to pressurize the ascent engine; a signal is sent to the LGC and AGS to compute and execute the abort
> trajectory, using the abort stage program; a signal is sent (via instrumentation) to telemetry to indicate that the LEM is preparing to stage for an abort; the descent engine is shut down; and an "engine
> on" command is enabled, which fires the appropriate electroexplosive
> device to initiate vehicle staging.The LGC simultaneously
> turns on the ascent engine, and signals telemetry, via serial down-link, that the ascent engine has been started.*

(emphasis mine)

Source: [LEM Familiarization Manual](https://www.ibiblio.org/apollo/Documents/Lunar%20Excursion%20Module%20Familiarization%20Manual%20-%20LMA790-1.pdf) page 3-8

This chart shows the capability of each engine to abort versus altitude and descent rate.

[image]

Source: [Apollo Lunar Landing Strategy](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.207.7507&rep=rep1&type=pdf)

Acronymology:

- AGS: Abort Guidance System
- LEM / LM: Lunar Module
- LGC: LM Guidance Computer

Here's an example of a page from the landing checklist from the [Timeline Book](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/58404/6944) with the abort callouts highlighted. (No acronymology will be supplied for this beast)

[image]

Comment: That graph is beautiful from an engineering standpoint, and from a graphic design standpoint.

Comment: Would it be accurate to summarize this as that the "abort stage" switch is an "abort + stage" switch?

Comment: I'm curious about the left end of the "descent engine" curve on that graph. Does that imply that using the descent engine below either 250 ft or 75 ft/s would be "unsuccessful", or would the curve continue all the way to the origin, as implied by the "nominal profile"?

Comment: @kgutwin: That close to the surface you have to use a different abort protocol involving firing the descent stage at full power first and then switching to the ascent engine.